# Paypal Express checkout reloads page after payment

Tags: javascript, .net, paypal

I added Express checkout button to my page and set-up server side process with client code:

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
    var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = "<create_payment_url>";
    var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = "<execute_payment_url>";

    paypal.Button.render({
        env: "sandbox",
        payment: function (resolve, reject) {
            return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL)
                .then(function (data) {
                    resolve(data.id);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    reject(err);
                });
        },
        onAuthorize: function (data) {
            return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, { paymentID: data.paymentID, payerID: data.payerID })
                .then(function (data) {
                    document.querySelector('#paypal-button').innerText = 'Payment Complete!';
                    console.log("Success", data);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log("Error", err);
                });
        }
    }, "#paypal-button");
</script>
```

I use server-side .NET SDK to create and process payment via generic handlers and it works fine, but after payment execution is called, whole page is reloaded.

I want to handle results/errors via executions listeners  - paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, ...) callbacks defined with .then() and .catch() methods.

For PayPal's interactive demo at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server listener works as expected.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Do you see any console errors? This shouldn't redirect or reload the page.

Comment: No, I don't. However when I used correct redirect_urls in CREATE_PAYMENT_URL script, it behave as expected. Details in my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that I used default redirect_urls in my create payment handler (CREATE_PAYMENT_URL), since I don't need them - responses are handled by JavaScript listeners. But redirect_urls is required parameter for Payment object. However, it seems that those redirect and cancel urls don't need to be correct, only server port should respond.

My server side code looks like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
string accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
Payer payer = new Payer()
{
    payment_method = "paypal"
};
RedirectUrls redirUrls = new RedirectUrls()
{
    cancel_url = "http://localhost:<correct_port>/some_cancel.ashx",
    return_url = "http://localhost:<correct_port>/some_return.ashx"
};
ItemList itemList = new ItemList()
{
    items = new List<Item>() {
    // Some items
}
};
Amount amount = new Amount()
{
    currency = "EUR",
    total = "##.##",
};
List<Transaction> transList = new List<Transaction>()
{
    new Transaction() {
        amount=amount,
        description="Desc...",
        invoice_number="#####",
        item_list=itemList
    }
};
Payment payment = new Payment()
{
    intent = "sale",
    payer = payer,
    transactions = transList,
    redirect_urls = redirUrls
};
Payment createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);
context.Response.Write(/*<Serialized response>*/);
```

There's another question I'd like to ask. When I login via sandbox buyer Paypal account, I can't change payment method, only Paypal balance is available. However, when I try demo (https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server), there is possibility to change payment method to Credit card bound to those account in Paypal. I use the same sandbox account for both tests.

Thanks.